# free memory when working with large matrices

Tags: matlab, memory-management

I am trying to use the following command:

```
X = H \ [ Xp(:) Yp(:) ones(wp*hp,1) ]';
```

where `Xp(:)` & `Yp(:)` are large matrices and am running into an "out of memory" error.I cannot clear any of the data in the workspace since it is needed for the rest of the processing.

*How can I divide this operation to blocks?
*Is it a good approach?
*What other options do I have?

this is a `memory` output just before this command:

```
Maximum possible array:        4005 MB (4.199e+09 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:        4005 MB (4.199e+09 bytes) *
Memory used by MATLAB:        1804 MB (1.891e+09 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):        4018 MB (4.213e+09 bytes)
```

Comment: How big are all the individual matrices you're working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a little on where the out of memory is occurring (i.e. in creating `[ Xp(:) Yp(:) ones(wp*hp,1) ]` or in calculating `X`).

The first thing I'd suggest is splitting the problem into separate operations along the lines of,

```
mat = [ Xp(:) Yp(:) ones(wp*hp,1) ]';
X = nan(size(H,2),size(mat,2));
for idx = 1:size(mat,2)
   X(:,idx) = H\mat(:,idx);
end
```

which will require less memory.

If the problem is in the size of `mat` then you can try

```
%mat = [ Xp(:) Yp(:) ones(wp*hp,1) ]';
X = nan(size(H,2),numel(Xp));
for idx = 1:numel(Xp)
   X(:,idx) = H\[Xp(idx); Yp(idx); 1];
end
```